# Как указать кастомный путь для paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Есть одно монолитное приложение, внутри есть два приложения - `app1` и `app2`.
Модели у них общие.
Файл создается в `app1`, и соответственно сохраняется в `app1:rails_root/public/...`.
и при вызове `ticket.document.url` второе приложение его не видит, так как обращается к `app2:rails_root/public/...`.

Наверное есть два выхода:
1) Как сохранять сразу во второе приложение?
1) Как указать url куда смотреть из второго приложения?

Comment: У меня есть вариант с разделением этих двух приложений на два контейнера с подключением к одной БД и использованием одного хранилища. Хранилище может быть как локальное, так и облачное. Хотя с другой стороны, если у вас одна БД и одни и те же файлы, то почему бы не разделить Rails приложение на модули?

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге я сделал общую папку (симлинк на `app1:rails_root/public/...`)